# Multiply Referenced Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I'd like to ask about adding multiply foreign keys, it's possible to add a foreign key to table, and add another key linked to another table .

My question is, How it's possible to make the same Foreign key, references for multiply columns in the same table ?

Example :

Table 'Categories' : Action, Comedy, Horror, Sci-Fi .
Table 'Movie' : Item_One .

A movie, can be referenced to a lot of categories, that's my question, What if i want to link that item to Action, Comedy, Horror in 'Categories', the way i know only let you reference a single column .

If there's a problem in the question asking way, please let me know .

Comment: Not sure you'd need a table for "Categories" or Genre. If you did, then you'd have a cross-reference table that just holds movie_id and category_id values

Comment: Categories/Genres, yes, chose the wrong word sorry. I'll google that, thanks! .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done using a many-to-many relation table, which has foreign keys to the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE MovieGenre (
    movieId INT,
    genreId INT,
    UNIQUE KEY (movieId, genreId),
    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (genreId) REFERENCES Genres (id)
)
```